# Lightweight Migration Issues in SwiftData

Tags: ios, swift-data

I am trying to run a lightweight migration in which I am changing the name of a model property from name to title. The database is already populated with few records. Those records must be preserved.

Here is my schema versions:

```
enum TripsSchemaV1: VersionedSchema {
    
    static var versionIdentifier: String? = "Initial version"
    
    static var models: [any PersistentModel.Type] {
        [Trip.self]
    }
    
    @Model
    class Trip {
        var name: String
        
        init(name: String) {
            self.name = name
        }
    }
}
enum TripsSchemaV2: VersionedSchema {
    
    static var versionIdentifier: String? = "name changed to title"
    
    static var models: [any PersistentModel.Type] {
        [Trip.self]
    }
    
    @Model
    class Trip {
        @Attribute(originalName: "name") var title: String
        
        init(title: String) {
            self.title = title
        }
    }
}
```

**Migration plan:**

```
enum TripsMigrationPlan: SchemaMigrationPlan {
    
    static var schemas: [any VersionedSchema.Type] {
        [TripsSchemaV1.self, TripsSchemaV2.self]
    }
    
    static var stages: [MigrationStage] {
        [migrateV1toV2]
    }
    
    static let migrateV1toV2 = MigrationStage.lightweight(fromVersion: TripsSchemaV1.self, toVersion: TripsSchemaV2.self)
    
}
```

And finally the usage:

```
@main
struct TripsApp: App {
    
    let container: ModelContainer
    
    init() {
           do {
               container = try ModelContainer(for: [Trip.self], migrationPlan: TripsMigrationPlan.self, ModelConfiguration(for: [Trip.self]))
           } catch {
               fatalError("Could not initialize the container.")
           }
       }
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .modelContainer(container)
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the app, all my data for the Trips is gone and I get the following message on the output window.

```
Unresolved error loading container Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134504 "Cannot use staged migration with an unknown c
```

Comment: Can you please file a feedback report and attach your store file?

Comment: This migration was successful in the latest beta.